# jtl to csv file conversion error through jmeter

Tags: html, csv, jmeter

I tried to convert `jmeter` `jtl` or `csv` file to html reports through using below command :

```
jmeter -g [path to result file] -o [path to report output folder]
```

But here I am seeing below error :

> ~/Documents/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin$ jmeter -g /home/Name/LoadTestResults/results.csv -o /home/Name/HTMLReports/
> Error: Unknown option -g
> Try 'jmeter --help' for more information.

Please let me know if any setting we need to update.

Answer (score 0):

Try out changing command to look like:

```
./jmeter -g /home/Name/LoadTestResults/results.csv -o /home/Name/HTMLReports/
```

which will execute [JMeter startup script](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.3/bin/jmeter) **from the current folder** as it looks like you're executing the other `jmeter` instance which is under your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) and it's version is lower than [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/your-top-3-questions-about-jmeter-30-%E2%80%93-answered) where HTML Reporting Dashboard was introduced.